# Excel - Formatting Latitudes and Longitudes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 1000 rows of latitudes in an Excel sheet. They are formatted e.g. "13.3N" or "16.8S" How would I change the format so that the latitudes ending in "S" will become negative, e.g. "16.8S" becomes "-16.8", and the ones ending in "N" become positive, e.g. "13.3N" becomes "13.3"?

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with it and managed to do this, which works:

=IF(RIGHT(B2,1)="S",-LEFT(B2,(LEN(B2)-1)),IF(RIGHT(B2,1)="N",LEFT(B2,(LEN(B2)-1)),B2*1))

Answer (score 0):

Another similar formula for data in A1:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1)="S",-1,1)*LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is in a range, and you have Microsoft 365, you can use this formula in some cell and the results will SPILL down to convert the entire range:

```
B7: =LET(
     lats, A7:A8,
     TEXTBEFORE(lats, {"N", "S"}) *
        IF(RIGHT(lats) = "N", 1, -1)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="N",NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"N","")),NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"S",""))*-1)
```

[image]